# .NET Compact Framework - modal Form without ShowDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way to show a modal form without ShowDialog metod calling? By showing a modal form I mean that the Form overlays the current Form and prevent user input to the bacground Form. The Form that is to be shown is a MessageBox style form that is not fullscreen.

Thanks

Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you could set the "dialog" form to stay on top (TopMost property) and then disable the main form in order to prevent input.

This is only a partial solution as the main form will still be able to be focused, closed etc. You will need to handle all these cases yourself in order to prevent them.

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use ShowDialog?

Comment: There are several reasons for not using `ShowDialog()`, the main problem is with tasking to other applications where tasking back to the said application will show the parent form as the to forms actually get their own task in task manager. Effectively you can't do anything on the parent form as it's denying input, but you can't get to the opened window because it's a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this:

```
    MyForm frm = new MyForm();  // this would be your modeless dialog
    frm->show(this);           // "this" being the instance that invokes it.
```

Comment: The `Show(Form)` overload is not available on the compact framework. Instead you must set the `Owner` property to the owning form, then call `Show()`.